# How do I create a command that searches a specific directory?

Tags: search, grep

I would like to create a command (C-s C-k or something?) that searches a specific directory every time I call it. It would search files within that directory for a string (may contain spaces) and then present me with a list of results and allow me to jump to said file/result.

I am trying to create a knowledge base of sorts using org files in a directory.

I am currently using a spacemacs setup with a few extra org-mode bits.

Comment: What's wrong with using [Emacs command `grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Grep-Searching.html) and related commands?

Comment: The issue is that I do it all the time, so I wanted a short version of it. Deft is doing the job quite nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package that you are looking for is called [deft](http://jblevins.org/projects/deft/).

As a spacemacs user you can just include it as a layer. Just `SPC h SPC` and type deft to get the instructions on how to use it.

Comment: This is excellent! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The following will ask for a search string and search all files with suffix ".org" in the indicated directory for that string. The resulting grep buffer allows you to click on the `filename:lineno` part of each matched line and takes you there:

```
(defun special-grep(s)
  (interactive "MSearch for string: ")
  (lgrep s "*.org" "/path/to/directory/"))


(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-z") (function special-grep))
```

I chose a different keybinding that was undefined in my installation. I think "C-s C-k" is a bad idea though, because C-s invokes interactive search and that might cause problems (although the keybinding I chose may be transgressing on the guidelines too - if so, I hope somebody will suggest a better key binding).

Comment: Hey there, I'm getting an error with this one: grep-expand-template: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil

Comment: Strange: it worked fine on one machine but I get the same error you get on another. I'll try to debug it a bit but it may take some time. If you run `M-x lgrep` and enter the three arguments, do you still get an error?

Comment: Try adding a slash at the end of the directory path. I added it in the answer and that seems to resolve the problem for me. I hope it works for you too.

Comment: Hmmm that's not working either but I'm on Windows and some searching seems to indicate various grep/lgrep related issues on that platform... Thank you for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are just looking for a command that always searches in the *same directory*.  All you need to do is bind **`default-directory`** around a command, such as `grep` that searches in the current directory by default.

```el
(defvar my-dir "/THIS/IS/YOUR/DIR/"
  "My directory.")

(defun grep-my-dir ()
  "Grep in `my-dir'."
  (interactive)
  (let ((default-directory  my-dir))
    (call-interactively #'grep)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-o") 'grep-my-dir)
```